# Oracle MySQL operator for kubernetes backup to S3 using service account

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, amazon-eks, mysql-operator

I've installed the operator, and trying to create the innodb cluster with backup profile which uses S3. There is no mention of S3 in the documentation, but they mentioned in a conference about S3 support. Found little source about the subject, which mentions set up something like this:
Secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aws-credentials
type: Opaque
data:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: <base64-encoded-access-key-id>
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: <base64-encoded-secret-access-key>
```

then the cluster definition:

```
apiVersion: mysql.oracle.com/v1
kind: MySQLCluster
metadata:
  name: my-mysql-cluster
spec:
  replicas: 3
  version: "8.0"
  backupProfiles:
    - name: s3-backup
      storageProvider: s3
      s3:
        region: <aws-region>
        bucketName: <s3-bucket-name>
        credentialsSecret:
          name: aws-credentials
```

All looks fine, but I'm using EKS cluster with OIDC, and I have service account defined  having access to S3 properly. My question is, is there any way to configure S3 backup profile without using the aws secret keys, but using the service account?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.